# Is there way to apply different .htaccess rules by time range?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security, post, ip-blocking

For security hardening, is there easier ways to automate below actions:

For example I would like to LIMIT any POST actions after 23:00 midnight those periods hackers are active. so if I put below .htaccess rules at the root of public_html, can block hacker to upload massive malicious files at midnight to some of unsecured sites while I'm sleeping.

```
<Limit POST> 
order deny,allow 
deny from all 
allow from 127.0.0.1 
allow from [MY IP]
</Limit>
```

while automatically comment out (not apply specific .htaccess rules)  during working hours in the day period when most valid users with diff IPs are able to access, login and upload stuff normally.

```
#<Limit POST> 
#order deny,allow 
#deny from all 
#allow from 127.0.0.1 
#allow from [MY IP]
#</Limit>
```

Comment: This sounds like an exercise in futility.

Comment: just dicussing for the easiest ways to achieve this, there might be a lot of approaches to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that by writing two scripts Script 1 will add that rule to htaccess and Script 2 will delete that rule from htaccess.

Schedule a Cron job that will run Script 1 at 11PM every day and another cron job that will run Script 2 at 8 AM every morning.

Comment: Ok, follow your tips I have managed to write php script to add / remove .htaccess rules  aromatically by detecting clock changes triggerd by cron job. such approach requires cronjob setting, php script , and .htaccess three files working together.